# VPN server in different timezone apparently ignored by NTP / location services

Tags: vpn, geolocation

I am using a WiFi router at home that tunnels all my traffic to a IPSec VPN server that is located in a different timezone. This way, all wireless clients automatically use this VPN connection. So far, so good.

While this works great in general and my "external" IP address appears to be the one of the VPN server, my Macbook Pro (Sonoma) still sets its timezone automatically to the actual location it is in. The same happens for the Weather app and FindMy.

I am a bit clueless here how this happens. My best guess is that Apple uses some sort of location detection mechanism that evades the VPN. How do I fix this? And: Is there any information on how apple location actually works?

Comment: Precise location on desktops is typically done by wifi scanning and comparing against a database of known BSSID/ESSID data.